# Blazor net8.0 and EPPlus 7.06 Worksheet position out of range

Tags: blazor, epplus, .net-8.0

I am trying to read an existing spreadsheet using Blazor server under net8.0 and the latest version of EPPlus (7.0.6). The spreadsheet I'm trying to read has 1 (one) worksheet. When I inspect the Worksheets collection it has a count of zero.

I tried to use the position Id of zero

```
using var package = new ExcelPackage("spreadsheet.xlsx");
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

Then I tried naming it

```
using var package = new ExcelPackage("spreadsheet.xlsx");
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["name"];
```

I know this works in net7.0 as I wrote a console app to do the same thing. But I need this to work in my Blazor App. It's obvious that it's not seeing/reading the sheet. Is this a bug in EPPlus?

I've also tried previous versions of EPPlus with the same result.

**Full Code**

```
@using OfficeOpenXml

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Test Spreadsheet</h1>

@if (errors.Any())
{
    <h2>Errors</h2>
    <ul class="text-danger">
        @foreach (var e in errors)
        {
            <li>@e</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private List<string> errors = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        errors.Clear();

        try
        {
            using var package = new ExcelPackage("spreadsheet.xlsx");
            var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[Results when this code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpbXj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I just worked this out for myself. Even though the ExcelPackage object is not null I needed the full path not just a relitive path to access the actual file.

My appogies to all.